# File manager with extra columns for different file types

Tags: filemanager

I'm in the search for a file manager with extended columns for files like JPG and MP3.

For pictures, I would like to be able to sort by date when the image was taken, and dimensions, etc.

For music, I would like columns like track number, bitrate, artitst, album, etc.

Is there an app like this? I was a windows user and I miss features like that.

Answer (score 1):

The Dolphin file manager provides some of the features you list.

From [The Dolphin Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/dolphin/dolphin-view.html):

In all view modes Dolphin shows at least an icon and a name for each item. Using Additional Information in the View menu or the context menu of the header in Details mode, you can select more information for each item to be shown:

Size, Date, Type, Rating, Tags or Comment.

Depending on the file type, additionally, sorting criteria can be selected:
Document: Number of words and lines
Image: Size and orientation
Audio: Artist, album, duration and track

The Other submenu allows you to select Path, Link Destination, Copied From, Permissions, Owner* or User Group.

Like many other file managers, Dolphin's utility can be extended by means of context-menu additions. See [Dolphin Service Menus](https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/102/page/2/ord/latest/) for more.